# Best practices to decide base resolutions for images and drawables

Tags: android, image, button, view

I understand that for performance, we should provide different resolutions for our drawables based on this scale:

•  xhdpi: 2.0

•  hdpi: 1.5

•  mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)

•  ldpi: 0.75

Now, if I want to create an image that for example will show in the center of the screen or as a background for a button, how to decide the starting resolution?

My practice is, for example, if I want an image to take 100 dp width and 50 dp hight on the screen, I would design a 200*100 px image, which is double the dp amount, so it shows up crisp. Should I consider this particular image to be the hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, or mdpi? so I scale it accordingly.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your image to be 100dp x 50dp, and your actual bitmap is 200px x 100px, then you would put that bitmap in `res/drawable-xhdpi/`. 200/100 is 2.0. 100/50 is 2.0. `-xhdpi` has a ratio of 2.0 over `-mdpi`, and in `-mdpi`, 1dp is 1px.

Comment: Thanks for answering, so if 100px * 50px goes to drawable-mdli, this means 100px * 50px = the actual dp dimension 100dp * 50dp, and dp refers to an independent pixel that in my understanding not necessarily equal to actual pixels, and 200px*100px isn't necessarily 2 times 100dp*50dp, right?

Comment: @fullMoon: "dp refers to an independent pixel that in my understanding not necessarily equal to actual pixels" -- 1dp == 1px for `-mdpi` devices. 1dp == 2px for `-xhdpi` devices. And so on for the other densities.